# Why do I get a line of code in my browser after creating a text area?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my view I see:

```
(#<Element id: 9, element_type: "paragraph", content: nil, post_id: 3, position: nil, created_at: "2021-07-15 14:35:49.860163000 +0000", updated_at: "2021-07-15 14:35:49.860163000 +0000">, #<Element id: nil, element_type: "paragraph", content: nil, post_id: 3, position: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>])
```

Here is my code

```
  <%= @post.elements.each do |element|%>
    <% if element.persisted?%>
        <%= form_with(model: [@post, element]) do |form|%>
        <%= form.text_area :content %>
        <%= form.submit "save", class: 'btn btn-primary'%>
      <%end%> 
    <%end%>
```

Comment: with `each` loop, you no need to return `<%=`, so your code should be `<% @post.elements.each do |element|%>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the equal in your code because you have .each

You can put the equal inside the .each statement

Here with your code

```
<% @post.elements.each do |element|%>
    <% if element.persisted?%>
        <%= form_with(model: [@post, element]) do |form|%>
        <%= form.text_area :content %>
        <%= form.submit "save", class: 'btn btn-primary'%>
      <%end%> 
    <%end%>
```

Comment: Can you please upvote my answer please :)